# How to retrieve keyManager details from SSLContext?

Tags: java, keystore, truststore, java-security, sslcontext

I would like to retrieve **credentialMap** belongs to keyManager from sslContext object.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws UnrecoverableKeyException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchProviderException, KeyManagementException {
        SSLContext sslContext = newServerContext(createKeyManagers());
        // how to get keyManager from sslContext?
    }

public static SSLContext newServerContext(KeyManager[] keyManagers)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException,
            KeyManagementException {
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(keyManagers, null, new SecureRandom());
        return ctx;
    }

public static KeyManager[] createKeyManagers()
            throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        FileInputStream keyStoreFile = new FileInputStream("F:\\IdeaProjects\\NewFeature\\keystore.jks");
        String keyStorePassword = "changeit";
        keyStore.load(keyStoreFile, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        return kmf.getKeyManagers();
    }
```

How can I retrieve keyManager details from ctx(SSLContext) object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you cannot get the `KeyManager` array through some methods of `SSLContext`. Why don't you hold the `KeyManager` array in a variable?

```
KeyManager[] keyManagers = createKeyManagers();
SSLContext sslContext = newServerContext(keyManagers);
```

By the way, why do you want to obtain the `KeyManager[]`  through `SSLContext`? What are you going to do with it? Where are you going to use it? The `SSLContext` acts as a factory for secure socket factories or SSLEngines. The KeyManager should be internally used by `SSLServerSocketFactory` or `SSLEngine`.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! It required for a test case, where as I am getting SSLContext from a class and would like to check its client alias which is available inside keyManager credentialMap. So, as you mentioned it's not possible in anyway?

Comment: I am trying to do this exact thing for a test as well. Did you find a solution? @SwadeepMohanty